# 'wx.media.MediaCtrl' on Mac OS keep failing on "Load(..)"

Tags: python, wxpython, mp3

i've been looking for a simple mp3 player example written in python and found this:
http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/20/wxpython-creating-a-simple-mp3-player/

i've been trying to run it but it fails on line 134 (when calling the 'Load' method)

error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "player_skeleton2.py", line 161, in onBrowse
self.loadMusic(path)
File "player_skeleton2.py", line 135, in loadMusic
wx.MessageBox("Unable to load %s: Unsupported format?" % path,
NameError: global name 'path' is not defined
```

i'm thinking that maybe it has something to do that i'm on Mac OS

can anybody help me with that or maybe provide me a different mp3 player example?

Thanks alot!

the player code:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# player_skeleton2.py
#
# Created: 04/15/2010
#
# Author: Mike Driscoll - mike@pythonlibrary.org
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

import os
import wx
import wx.media
import wx.lib.buttons as buttons

dirName = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
bitmapDir = os.path.join(dirName, 'bitmaps')

########################################################################
class MediaPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        self.frame = parent
        self.currentVolume = 50
        self.createMenu()
        self.layoutControls()

        sp = wx.StandardPaths.Get()
        self.currentFolder = sp.GetDocumentsDir()

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.onTimer)
        self.timer.Start(100)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def layoutControls(self):
        """
        Create and layout the widgets
        """

        try:
            self.mediaPlayer = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)

        except NotImplementedError:
            self.Destroy()
            raise

        # create playback slider
        self.playbackSlider = wx.Slider(self, size=wx.DefaultSize)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.onSeek, self.playbackSlider)

        self.volumeCtrl = wx.Slider(self, style=wx.SL_VERTICAL|wx.SL_INVERSE)
        self.volumeCtrl.SetRange(0, 100)
        self.volumeCtrl.SetValue(self.currentVolume)
        self.volumeCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.onSetVolume)

        # Create sizers
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        audioSizer = self.buildAudioBar()

        # layout widgets
        mainSizer.Add(self.playbackSlider, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        hSizer.Add(audioSizer, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        hSizer.Add(self.volumeCtrl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(hSizer)

        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        self.Layout()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def buildAudioBar(self):
        """
        Builds the audio bar controls
        """
        audioBarSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.buildBtn({'bitmap':'player_prev.png', 'handler':self.onPrev,
                       'name':'prev'},
                      audioBarSizer)

        # create play/pause toggle button
        img = wx.Bitmap(os.path.join(bitmapDir, "player_play.png"))
        self.playPauseBtn = buttons.GenBitmapToggleButton(self, bitmap=img, name="play")
        self.playPauseBtn.Enable(False)

        img = wx.Bitmap(os.path.join(bitmapDir, "player_pause.png"))
        self.playPauseBtn.SetBitmapSelected(img)
        self.playPauseBtn.SetInitialSize()

        self.playPauseBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onPlay)
        audioBarSizer.Add(self.playPauseBtn, 0, wx.LEFT, 3)

        btnData = [{'bitmap':'player_stop.png',
                    'handler':self.onStop, 'name':'stop'},
                    {'bitmap':'player_next.png',
                     'handler':self.onNext, 'name':'next'}]
        for btn in btnData:
            self.buildBtn(btn, audioBarSizer)

        return audioBarSizer

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def buildBtn(self, btnDict, sizer):
        """"""
        bmp = btnDict['bitmap']
        handler = btnDict['handler']

        img = wx.Bitmap(os.path.join(bitmapDir, bmp))
        btn = buttons.GenBitmapButton(self, bitmap=img, name=btnDict['name'])
        btn.SetInitialSize()
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, handler)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.LEFT, 3)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def createMenu(self):
        """
        Creates a menu
        """
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()

        fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        open_file_menu_item = fileMenu.Append(wx.NewId(), "&Open", "Open a File")
        menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
        self.frame.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        self.frame.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onBrowse, open_file_menu_item)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def loadMusic(self, musicFile):
        """"""
        if not self.mediaPlayer.Load(musicFile):
            wx.MessageBox("Unable to load %s: Unsupported format?" % path,
                          "ERROR",
                          wx.ICON_ERROR | wx.OK)
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.SetInitialSize()
            self.GetSizer().Layout()
            self.playbackSlider.SetRange(0, self.mediaPlayer.Length())
            self.playPauseBtn.Enable(True)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onBrowse(self, event):
        """
        Opens file dialog to browse for music
        """
        wildcard = "MP3 (*.mp3)|*.mp3|"     \
                   "WAV (*.wav)|*.wav"
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(
            self, message="Choose a file",
            defaultDir=self.currentFolder, 
            defaultFile="",
            wildcard=wildcard,
            style=wx.OPEN | wx.CHANGE_DIR
            )
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dlg.GetPath()
            self.currentFolder = os.path.dirname(path)
            self.loadMusic(path)
        dlg.Destroy()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onNext(self, event):
        """
        Not implemented!
        """
        pass

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onPause(self):
        """
        Pauses the music
        """
        self.mediaPlayer.Pause()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onPlay(self, event):
        """
        Plays the music
        """
        if not event.GetIsDown():
            self.onPause()
            return

        if not self.mediaPlayer.Play():
            wx.MessageBox("Unable to Play media : Unsupported format?",
                          "ERROR",
                          wx.ICON_ERROR | wx.OK)
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.SetInitialSize()
            self.GetSizer().Layout()
            self.playbackSlider.SetRange(0, self.mediaPlayer.Length())

        event.Skip()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onPrev(self, event):
        """
        Not implemented!
        """
        pass

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onSeek(self, event):
        """
        Seeks the media file according to the amount the slider has
        been adjusted.
        """
        offset = self.playbackSlider.GetValue()
        self.mediaPlayer.Seek(offset)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onSetVolume(self, event):
        """
        Sets the volume of the music player
        """
        self.currentVolume = self.volumeCtrl.GetValue()
        print "setting volume to: %s" % int(self.currentVolume)
        self.mediaPlayer.SetVolume(self.currentVolume)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onStop(self, event):
        """
        Stops the music and resets the play button
        """
        self.mediaPlayer.Stop()
        self.playPauseBtn.SetToggle(False)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onTimer(self, event):
        """
        Keeps the player slider updated
        """
        offset = self.mediaPlayer.Tell()
        self.playbackSlider.SetValue(offset)

########################################################################
class MediaFrame(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Python Music Player")
        panel = MediaPanel(self)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MediaFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: When you say it fails that's not very clear what the problem is, showing the error traceback that you get would be usefull.

Comment: i added my error msg i got... thanks for any help..

Comment: Looks like my blog's code example has a bug in it. See Yoriz's answer for the solution while I update the post on my blog.

Comment: Personally, I like the MplayerCtrl a little better than the MediaCtrl that's built into wxPython

Comment: Hi, thanks alot for your comment... what i dont understand is why "not self.mediaPlayer.Load(musicFile)" == True in the first place

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the variable path is not defined anywhere in the code.

Try changing

```
wx.MessageBox("Unable to load %s: Unsupported format?" % path,
```

to

```
wx.MessageBox("Unable to load %s: Unsupported format?" % musicFile,
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but it's not so helpful.. it's clear what this error means.. i just dont understand why the program run this code in the first place...

Comment: meaning: why is "not self.mediaPlayer.Load(musicFile)" == True